# Strange CommandParameter with View.CurrentItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have in `ViewModel` a collection, with `ICollectionView view;` Well, in XAML I have

`<Button ... Command="cmdDelete" CommandParameter="{Binding view.CurrentItem}" />`

But it's strange because the `CommandParameter` is not resolved at the time of click. I get some values which don't reflect the `CurrentItem`.

**Update:** View is created as `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(observablecollection);` and this collection is bound to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource`.

Comment: Where did you define the view?

Comment: And what is bound to the view? What is changing the CurrentItem? Basically, not enough info ;)

Comment: Just a thought... you can bind a `ViewModel's` object with `DataGrid's SelectedItem` and use that object inside your command's method if you don't find out a direct solution of this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding view/}"
```

Comment: What is the meaning of that slash? IT WORKED! :-)